# Is nodejs' hashlib supported when installed on FreeBSD?

Tags: node.js, hashlib

I've attempted to install hashlib on FreeBSD and it looks like there are some problems with it. Before I dig any deeper to try and solve them, is a setup having NodeJS and hashlib running on FreeBSD something that's tested/supported for hashlib/nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.JS runs fine on FreeBSD, however, there is a known issue when trying to compile hashlib on FreeBSD, see: https://github.com/brainfucker/hashlib/issues/7

Comment: you may want to message the author directly to see if there is a workaround